# combine dataframes and match unique ID and address

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in pandas. Each of the dataframes are from 2 excel files that Im using that I've imported.  DF1 has 29+ columns and DF2 has 7. DF has address info and Zip codes and a unique identifier and I need to combine both data frames and provide the unique identifier on the 2nd one. I wrote a function in python that cleans up the zip codes in both DFs. and I've named the column "zip code_fixed" in both columns.

```
def_zip(series):
       return series.astype(str).str[:5].str.zfill(5)
```

I then merged the two dataframes and it looks like it appears to have worked! Here's the code that I used:

```
df7 = pd.merge(DF1, DF2)[['Customer Supplier Number', 'State_fixed', 'Zip Code_fixed, 'Address Line 1_fixed"]]
```

I did a few tests and it appears to have worked! the unique ID is correct after the merge.
Now I wanted to take that DF7 and merge it to my original dataframe so that I can have the matched results line up with the results on the DF1.

I tried:

```
result = pd.concat([DF2, df7], axis = 1, ignore_index = True, sort=False
```

The two dataframes merged but the unique IDs were not correct. I feel like Im missing a step somewhere. Does anyone have any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Is ID in the index of the dataframe?  If not pd.concat can and will have duplicate ID.  the reason, pd.merge work is that merge will merge on all common columns between the dataframes if 'on' or 'right_on' and 'left_on' are not defined.

Comment: Try `results = pd.conat([df1.set_index('ID'), df2.set_index('ID')], axis=1....`